# Privoxy with multiple instances of Tor

Tags: configuration, windows

I am running (testing environment) Windows 8.1 64bit and I have configured multiple instances of Tor.
I am using Privoxy to use .NET C# HttpWebRequest. It work perfectly, with single Tor instance.

Do I have to run also multiple instances of Privoxy? Is it possible to configure single instance of Privoxy to handle multiple Tor instances?

Thank you